# xml parsing error of the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

When I run the query below, I get the following error

> Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XML parsing: line 31, character 19, illegal qualified name character

Query:

```
;WITH xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition',
                     'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd)
SELECT
    a.Name,
    x.value('CommandType[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS CommandType,
    x.value('CommandText[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS CommandText
FROM 
    (SELECT
     name, 
     CAST(CAST(content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS reportXML 
     FROM  
     ReportServer.dbo.Catalog) a
    CROSS APPLY 
     a.reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query') r(x)
WHERE 
     x.value('CommandType[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') = 'StoredProcedure'
```

Comment: What is the *real* datatype of `content` in your table? I don't understand why you're casting to `VARBINARY(MAX)` first - doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me, since you're dealing with **XML** which is a **text-based** format (not a *binary* format)

Comment: datatype of content is image. database is SSRS database. it is the query i found on web to get report names and their stored procedures.

Comment: Is it possible, that there's an element not valid in the given namespace?